# Trying to find a simple ISS (Instruction Set Simulator) or any core for educational purpose in embedded systems

Tags: c++, c, simulation, embedded-systems

I want to start courses series on SoC virtualization using SystemC/TLM, I'm trying to find some easy ISS that I can integrate.

QEMU is a good example but it's too much for what I want, integrate it to SystemC is not that easy (there is an existing library mabe by Greensocs but it's not free to use ...) . Ideal would be an ISS written in C++, that can be easily integrated/connected to a SystemC platform (Data bus to access peripherals registers and memories, also support of minimal interrupt mecanisms).

Using some compiler be able to compile C code and then program the virtual platform.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I'll use : https://github.com/ultraembedded/armv6m-sim

Which seems to match my needs, and the github contains other projects of virtualized platforms that I can reuse.